# Yii2 website e.g. http://www.website.org.in/site/post/tree-plantation-ballab-haryana gives 404 error on enable rewrite rules

Tags: url, url-rewriting, yii2-advanced-app

After enabling rewrite rules it is working fine with id in yii2 but if I tried it with custom alias it is showing 404 error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.org.in$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website.org.in/$1 [L,R=301] 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* RewriteRule .* ? [F,L] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Config

```
'urlManager' => [
    'baseUrl' => $baseUrl, 
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
       '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ]
]
```

Comment: Please add some code so other users can test what you're describing. Thanks!

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on  
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.org.in$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.org.in/$1 [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
  RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]   
</IfModule> 'urlManager' => [ 'baseUrl' => $baseUrl, 'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 'showScriptName' => false,'rules' => ['<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',]]

Comment: Please edit your question